# How to split a Formik / React form into different columns in a table?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, formik

I'm learning ReactJS and using the Formik library for user input.

I've been trying to design a table whose first row (header) contains input fields for each of the columns displayed, but I can't seem to find a way to distribute said fields on their own columns. They all get crammed into the first column of the table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        {/* TODO: Fix this form as it currently loads into a single column */}
        <Formik
          initialValues={hobbyInitialValues}
          onSubmit={SubmitHobby}
          validationSchema={ValidateHobby}
        >
          <Form>
            <Field className="selectField" as="select" name="passion">
              <option value="" label="Select Passion" />
              <option value="Low" label="Low" />
              <option value="Medium" label="Medium" />
              <option value="High" label="High" />
            </Field>
            <Field
              className="inputField"
              id="inputHobbyName"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Enter User Hobby"
            />
            <Field
              className="inputField"
              id="inputYear"
              name="year"
              placeholder="Enter Year"
            />
            <button className="submitButton" type="submit">
              Add
            </button>
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Attempting to surround a single field within a  results in this error, as both Formik and React Tables restrict what children can a component have:

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.`

How can I achieve the intended result?

**EDIT:** my issue was solved thanks to Wraithy's answer. Code is now as follows:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={hobbyInitialValues}
  onSubmit={SubmitHobby}
  validationSchema={ValidateHobby}
>
  <Form>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            <Field className="selectField" as="select" name="passion">
              <option value="" label="Select Passion" />
              <option value="Low" label="Low" />
              <option value="Medium" label="Medium" />
              <option value="High" label="High" />
            </Field>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <Field
              className="inputField"
              id="inputHobbyName"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Enter User Hobby"
            />
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <Field
              className="inputField"
              id="inputYear"
              name="year"
              placeholder="Enter Year"
            />
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <button className="submitButton" type="submit">
              Add
            </button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap your whole `Table` in `<Formik>`

```
 <Formik
          initialValues={hobbyInitialValues}
          onSubmit={SubmitHobby}
          validationSchema={ValidateHobby}
        >
<table>
<!-- table with more columns go there -->
</table>
</Formik>
```